# Deploying Question2Answer

Tags: mysql, openshift, question2answer

I tried to deploy [Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/install.php). These are the steps I followed:

1. Create PHP 5.4 cartridge
2. Create MySQL 5.5 cartridge
3. Clone the PHP repo locally and add the contents of question2answer-latest.zip
4. Create qa-config.php from the example and adapt the MySQL credentials:

   ```
   define('QA_MYSQL_HOSTNAME', 'getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST")'); // try '127.0.0.1' or 'localhost' if MySQL on same server

   define('QA_MYSQL_USERNAME', 'taken from cartridge');

   define('QA_MYSQL_PASSWORD', 'taken from cartridge');

   define('QA_MYSQL_DATABASE', 'taken from cartridge');
   ```

Then I pushed the changes and opened the URL to my application. However, all I get is an empty white page.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The above `getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST")` variable did not work for me. Therefore, I ssh'ed into my application and found the HOST IP through `$ env | grep mysql`. It gave me something like the following:

`OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL=mysql://adminrszuv:rerewr9kGp2MpE@127.11.72.130:3316/`